# Does The Witcher 2 record your play time for save files individually?

Tags: steam, the-witcher-2

Does The Witcher 2 record your play time for each save game separately? I have it on Steam.

Comment: On what format?

Comment: Steam records your playtime, if you're interested in how long you've been playing the game.

Comment: Question is now worded better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the question.

**Unfortunately, you cannot view your play time for specific save files on The Witcher 2.**

Quote from [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-the-witcher-2-assassins-of-kings/59175761):

> If you're using the Steam version, it will tell you your overall play time with the game. Not for specific save files though.

Answer (score 1):

All games you buy on Valve Platform will record your playtime if you're playing them while connected to Steam servers.

Comment: Sorry, I realised I worded my question badly :/ I wanted to know if it records the playtime for each save game separately. I've updated my question.

Comment: Oh ok, then it depends of the game ! I don't remember that W2 records the time you spend in game, but it is possible.